# Pygame PNG image looks corrupt

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm following [this guide](http://www.nerdparadise.com/tech/python/pygame/basics/part2/) to try and display a basic PNG image inside a Pygame window. My image is a simple 150x150 green ball with no transparency called `ball.png`, located in the same directory as my Python script:

[image: Ball.png]

However, when I start my program, all that appears is a glitchy image of the correct size and location:

[image]

I am using this code to display the image (identical to the code given in the tutorial linked above):

```
import pygame
import os

_image_library = {}
def get_image(path):
        global _image_library
        image = _image_library.get(path)
        if image == None:
                canonicalized_path = path.replace('/', os.sep).replace('\\', os.sep)
                image = pygame.image.load(canonicalized_path)
                _image_library[path] = image
        return image

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 300))
done = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        done = True
        screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
        screen.blit(get_image('ball.png'), (20, 20))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)
```

Why would this happen? Is there a flaw in the code? I have tried replacing the PNG with different ones, but that just changes how the glitchy image looks - the image is still not displayed correctly. I'm using OS X 10.11 El Capitan, Python 3.5.0 and Pygame 1.9.2.

Comment: What is that path replacement stuff supposed to do exactly?

Comment: @xXliolauXx The `get_image` function is supposed to store images that have already been loaded according to the tutorial. It doesn't appear to be the problem though, because if I change the function to just `return pygame.image.load(path).convert()` the issue still occurs.

Comment: Pygame + El Capitan is known to have several rendering problems. When I run this code on my machine (Windows 10) everything looks fine. You can look here for more information: https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issues/284/max-osx-el-capitan-using-the-deprecated on how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @DJ McGoathem said, Pygame has known issues with El Capitan due to differing versions of the `SDL_image` library; Pygame needs version 1.2.10 but El Capitan has 1.2.12. This can be solved by downgrading this library, which I did like this (requires Brew):

1. Copy [this code](https://gist.github.com/AaronC81/ecfd395275568135860f) into a file called `sdl_image.rb`
2. Open a Terminal inside the directory where you saved that file
3. Run `brew remove sdl_image` to uninstall the incompatible version of the library
4. Run `brew install -f sdl_image.rb` to install the compatible version of the library

After this, my program was rendering the image correctly.

Comment: Seems a very nice answer, issue and solution well described. +1

Answer (score 0):

No problem when doing the source code under pygame 2.1.2, python 3.9 and macOs 12.6.1.  Just find a ball.png file and it displayed.  I have other pygame so far all ok.

Still the pygame_card sample app is not working which leads me to here.  I suspect the requirement to access all keyboard form all apps plus this require me to dig into it further.  But SDL may have update and all good for general cases.