# Pygame loads glitched versions of the original images

Tags: python, pygame

Hello Stacked Overflow Community!!

I've been a long time browser of this community but a first time poster.
I'm only posting because I'm desperate as well. When I import images in pygame, certain images get messed up beyond repair. I import images with the built-in pygame.image.load(filename) and the weird grayscale image is a JPG and the weird messed up pixelated one is a PNG. I don't transform the picture in any meaningful way except when I was trying to bug fix. I will provide the relevant code below. Thanks so much for the help in advance, it means a lot

```
class Alarm(MySprite):  

def __init__(self,image,x,y,radius,boundaries = None):
    MySprite.__init__(self,image,x,y)

    self.radius = radius
```

## -------------------------

```
def draw(self,screen):
    MySprite.draw(self,screen)


self.fireAlarmImage = pygame.image.load("fireAlarm.png")

if self.editing:
            self.background = Background(
                            "editing_background%d.jpg"%(self.level), True)

def set_background(self, picture = None):
    if picture:
        self.background = pygame.image.load(picture).convert_alpha()
```

[Weird Perspective/Greyscale/ParticiallyDuplicated/Shifted Pygame Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UWxOk.png)

[Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l3Btl.png)

Comment: I have more glitchy image screenshots but couldn't post them due to not having enough reputation. If you are interested in helping me, please pm me to see more

Comment: UPDATE: tried using the method fromhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/35384036/pygame-png-image-looks-corrupt/35385411 However, if I try doing what it says to do in this comment, I get "pygame.error: File is not a Windows BMP File"

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by uninstalling python and pygame and reinstalling.